# Login to network account on OSX when Mac server is uncontactable

Tags: macos, login

I have a Mac Server that the mac users on the network login to. All works fine and as expected.

However, if for any reason the mac server is uncontactable, you cannot log into the mac. Is there any way, (you can on windows I think) to cache the login so that they can still logon without the server being available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a "mobile account".

When you are using OpenDireczory you can enable a user as a mobile user. As soon as a user logs into a client machine all information will be transfered to the client and when the server is nit reachable this cached information will be used for authentication. But this only works when the user has already logged into the client once before the server was unreachable.